# me está dando un problema de importación en el deploy de pytonanywhere no me importa flask_mail

Tags: python-requests

Me da error de importación en flask_mail Ya lo he depurado un poco en los errores del deploy me pone no module named flask_mail tengo también el error en mi entorno gracias – en mi entorno si me manda los mails a ver alguno que ya ha hecho deploy muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes describir mejor el problema y agregar el código? No sé de flask pero lo que mencionas me da a pensar que se trata de una advertencia y no de un error, como cuando cuando declaras una variable y no la usas.

Comment: Ya lo he depurado un poco en los errores del deploy me pone no module named flask_mail tengo también el error en mi entorno gracias

Comment: Sigo sin poder hacerlo ya he probado a cambiar el intérprete de Python pero nada

Answer (score 0):

Al final cambie flask mail por envío stmp y tuve que usar Gmail como servidor mail stmp por qué en las páginas gratuitas de pythonanywhere es el que funciona y ya se puede ver

https://Rhommelsoft.pythonanywhere.com